# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGQt

Tags: c++, qt, root-framework

This question was asked many times, but nothing helped in my case. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 and trying to compile my Qt project with (CERN) ROOT libraries included. I am getting this error

```
13:07:23: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/mnt/kello/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib -o verifix main.o qrc_qml.o   /mnt/kello/root-6.08.06/lib/liblzma.a -L/opt/ROOT/root-6.10.08/lib -lGui -lCore -lImt -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lTree -lTreePlayer -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -lMultiProc -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic -lGQt -L/mnt/kello/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Quick -lQt5Gui -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 

**/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGQt**

Makefile:257: recipe for target 'verifix' failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [verifix] Error 1
```

I am sure my root is properly compiled and libGQt.so is present in opt/ROOT/root-6.10.08/lib

I have added INCLUDEPATH += /opt/ROOT/root-6.08.06/lib into my .pro file and also included rootcint.pri

Comment: Try to provide path to the library: `LIBS += -L"path/to/lib" -lGQt`. `INCLUDEPATH` is intended for header files

Comment: Yep thx, it helped. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to folibis, solved by removing `INCLUDEPATH` and adding `LIBS += -L"path/to/lib" -lGQt` to .pro file.